# Symfony 4 - Forms CollectionType get specific data

Tags: php, forms, symfony, collections, formbuilder

I have two kind of entities : "Affaire" and "Pointage". My Affaire Entity has a OneToMany relation with my Pointage Entity :

```
//App\Entity\Affaire.php

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Pointage", mappedBy="numAffaire")
 */
    private $pointages;
```

```
//App\Entity\Pointage.php

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Affaires", inversedBy="pointages")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
    private $numAffaire;
```

I created a form for my Affaire Entity which get "Pointages" related to a "Affaire".

```
//App\Form\AffaireType.php

class AffaireType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('numAffaire');
        $builder->add('descAffaire');
        $builder->add('pointages', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => PointageType::class,
            'entry_options' => ['label' => false, 'pointages' => $options['pointages']],
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setRequired(['pointages']);
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Affaires::class,
        ]);
    }

}
```

```
//App\Form\PointageType.php

class PointageType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('heurePointage');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setRequired(['pointages']);
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Pointage::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

My question is : how can I filter the "Pointages" in my AffaireType class ? For example, I want to get all the pointages associated to my Affaire where the id of my pointages is less than 100. Is it possible to make a query somewhere ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**!!! I would strongly advise against what you're doing there !!!**

#### Reason:

Your form type's data class is set to an entity (as far as I can tell). And the form is designed to **modify** the object it is given (your entity). Now, if you filter a field for that form type, and the form then tries to set the "new" values, all `Pointage` objects that are not in the form submission (specifically all those that were filtered *out*) might be **removed**. You will lose data, if the form calls `setPointages` - I'm not quite certain, if this is always called, even despite `allow_add`/`allow_remove` set to false. If you ever forget, this can make your life miserable. And I believe this is always called, for the standard `CollectionType`.

***update after some code reading:*** regarding the calling of `setPointages`: if `addPointage`/`removePointage` exist, they will be called. However, the previous value is read by the `PropertyAccessor` (property-access component) from the target object(!), and the difference will be calculated and add/remove called accordingly -> removing any entities not in the new collection

#### Possible workarounds

- Make heavy use of data mapper / data transformers / form events to *somehow* hide the fact that there are more `Pointage` entities. this might work *very* well, but it complicates stuff a lot but still might become a clean solution.

  the general idea is:

  - form render: get from entity(affaire, all pointages) -> your transformer/mapper/form event handler (affaire, **all -> filtered** pointages) -> form (affaire, filtered pointages)
  - form submit: form (affaire, filtered pointages) -> your transformer/mapper/form event handler (affaire, **filtered -> "new all"** pointages) -> set on entity (affaire, all pointages)

  however, you probably have to spend a lot of time understanding the internals of the form component to do this correctly and safely ... (one pointer would be the [`MergeCollectionListener`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5d94ace5ea4d51d64db2840306db0d6a566e55cd/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/EventListener/MergeCollectionListener.php), which you might be able to adapt to your needs, you might also take a look at the [`ResizeFormListener`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5d94ace5ea4d51d64db2840306db0d6a566e55cd/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/EventListener/ResizeFormListener.php), which adds and remove sub forms depending on the given data. remember if you filter your data, you should probably create your own collection type and add a new form listener that handles everything gracefully)
- instead of integrating this into the `AffaireType`, add another form type `AffairePointageType` with two fields: `affaire` (`AffaireType` without `pointages`) and `pointages` (`CollectionType`) and call it like

  ```
  $filteredPointages = someFilterFunction($affaire->getPointages());
  $this->createForm(AffairePointageType::class, [
       'affaire' => $affaire,
       'pointages' => $filteredPointages,
  ], [
       'pointages' => ... //the option you provide for the CollectionType
  ]);
  ```

  where you obviously can provide any pointages, filtered by any filter you like and will only edit those you provide, leaving anything else associated with `$affaire` untouched. Note, however, that you have to take care of added or removed pointages yourself. (this might break separation of concerns though)

  essentially, this is an easier to understand version of the previous workaround, where all filter logic is external, but since the form doesn't communicate "You can edit pointages of the affaire", but instead "you can simultaneously edit an affaire and a set of pointages, which might or might not be related", it's semantically clear and doesn't surprise future users (you included).

However, I believe you're approach might be flawed... but since it's unclear what you're actually trying to achieve, it's hard to propose a proper solution.

If it's just "there are too many (sub) forms displayed" - then it's more of a display issue, that can and probably should be fixed via javascript or css (`display:none`) or both. (which are imho nicer approaches, that don't mess with form logic and/mechanics).

Comment: Thank you for your advices, I'll try your workarounds ! :)